# Why does this Javascript alert fire?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, xss

I have been looking into preventing XSS attacks, and so am encoding values when they are rendered back to the client. This works fine, but when the value is placed into a .NET runat server input and this is rendered as below on the client the alert fires, even though the javascript has been encoded.

```
<input name="ctl00$body$buildTitle" type="text" value="&amp;lt;script&amp;gt;alert(&amp;#39;Hola&amp;#39;)&amp;lt;/script&amp;gt;" />
```

Can anyone explain why?

Comment: That does not fire the JS: http://jsbin.com/vimapepuni/1/edit?html,output

Comment: It doesn't fire for me if I render it locally - also, I didn't think script placed inside an `input` would be executed by the browser? (escaped or not)

Comment: Yes I tried on JsFiddle and noticed the same thing, although this is definitely happening on my site, and that is the only alert contained in the source

Comment: Either something is transforming that code before it is sent to the browser, or you have another alert somewhere that you haven't found yet.

Comment: Thanks James, this is exactly what i thought which is why I am confused. Im going to try and isolate at what point the alert fires and ill edit post if I find anything unusual

Comment: There must be some code (either client-side or server-side) that actually reads the value of your input, and then renders it in the html document, either by `document.write` or `.appendChild()`, by `Response.Write` or setting the `Text` property of something server-side, or some other method. Change from `alert("Hola");` to `debugger;` and refresh. That will allow you to check the stack trace using your browser's debugger.

Comment: good suggestion atornblad, ill try that now

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I have just searched the dom rather than the source and an unencoded version string was being used in a hidden div for some reason, so I gave everyone a red herring.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have rendered a Script block on client browser.
Irrespective of where you have placed a script block browser runs script.